# Function return wait for callback result

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class, with 'tax' var. I need fill this var when the request is complete.

The problem is that if I return into callback, this return is for callback function, not for my method, and if I return in a taxMethod, it is executed before that I have the data, because is async and request async.

```
class Myclass{

    constructor(){
     this.tax = this.taxMethod()
    }

    taxMethod(){

     let data = 0;
        this.simpleRequest(url,function(data){         

           data = Number(data[0].tx)
           return data //Return of callback

        }.bind(this))
      return data //Empty data
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll never be able to return asynchronous data from a function ... your choices are - 1. Callback, 2. Promise, 3. Async/Await

Comment: The callback `function(data){}` is fired in a new thread after the server returned data. All you need to do is put the data into `this.tax`, instead of returning it. In `constructor()`, you just call `this.taxMethod()` without assigning it directly to `this.tax`. It's not the cleanest of solutions, but the most basic.

Comment: try to assign some global Valerie, assign it to default, inside taxMethod function, store the value, and use it, after some delay...

Comment: if you dont know async , use settimeout...but its bad habit...

Comment: @JaromandaX `await` is just a different way of consuming promises, `taxMethod`/`simpleRequest` would still need to create a promise

Comment: @Bergi - I know that, and anyone reading into it would know that, I separated `Promise` and `await` because you can do `Promise` without `await` :p

Comment: class MyClass {
    constructor(){
            this.taxMethod(function(data){
                data = Number(data[0].txt);
                this.tax =data;
                console.log("tax", this.tax);
            }.bind(this));
    }
    taxMethod(callback){
        this.simpleRequest("url", function(data){
            callback(data);
        });
    }

    simpleRequest(url, callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            let fakeParm = [{txt:"123.21"}];
            callback(fakeParm);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

let myInstance = new MyClass();